# Omitting struct value when creating swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

rookie here, this may be a simple question but lets say I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct User: Codable, Identifiable {
  let id: String
  let firstname: String
  let lastname: String
  let age: Int
}
```

This is the basic user model, but when i create a new user i basically need the same struct with no id:

```
struct UserCreate: Codable {
  let firstname: String
  let lastname: String
  let age: Int
}
```

Seems quite verbose to create two structs. Is there a better pattern for this sort of thing?

Thanks

Comment: Make it optional, `let id: String?`

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you want?

```
 struct UserWithID: Codable, Identifiable {
  let id: String
      struct User: Codable {
      let firstname: String
      let lastname: String
      let age: Int
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set id as an optional and use other object in `User`

```swift
struct User: Codable, Identifiable {
  let id: String?
  let userCreate: UserCreate
}

struct UserCreate: Codable {
  let firstname: String
  let lastname: String
  let age: Int
}
```

---

You can just set `id` as an optional and use this object

```swift
struct User: Codable, Identifiable {
  let id: String?
  let firstname: String
  let lastname: String
  let age: Int
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just give a default value for `id`.

```
let id = UUID().uuidString
```